# Random posts in Hexo

Tags: ejs, hexo

I wanted to show 5 random posts on my home page using [Hexo](https://hexo.io/), but can't seem to get it working?! I changed ***'date'*** to ***'random'*** but didn't work.

**The code:**

```
<ul>
  <% site.posts.sort('date', -1).limit(5).each(function(post){ %>
    <li>
      <a href="<%- url_for(post.path) %>"><%= post.title || '(no title)' %></a>
    </li>
  <% }) %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`shuffle`](https://zespia.tw/warehouse/query.js.html#line132) or the alias [`random`](https://zespia.tw/warehouse/query.js.html#line132) will work:

```
<ul>
  <% site.posts.random().limit(5).each(function(post){ %>
    <li>
      <a href="<%- url_for(post.path) %>"><%= post.title || '(no title)' %></a>
    </li>
  <% }) %>
</ul>
```

How it works:

Hexo uses [Warehouse](https://github.com/tommy351/warehouse) for its database.  `posts` is a Query object.  So to modify the posts in the future just find the right database Query method in the [warehouse API](https://zespia.tw/warehouse/). Each Query method returns a modified copy of the previous Query so that the methods can be chained.  So if you want to modify it again just find another method and chain it.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much Shawn! :) this worked a charm! I was racking my brain on this one but see what I was missing. Thank you again!

Comment: @user5898548 no problem, glad I could help :)